# Validate WebService message against Schematron

Tags: java, web-services, validation, schematron

I have generated a web service client using JAX-WS and wsimport.

This is my client code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:9999/ws/processstuff?wsdl");
QName qname = new QName("namespace", "ProcessStuffImplService");
Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
ProcessStuffInterface processStuffInterface = service.getPort(ProcessStuffInterface.class);

ProcessStuffObject processStuffObject = new ProcessStuffObject();
//Web service call
processStuffInterface.processStuff(processStuffObject);
```

I need to validate `processStuffObject` against given Schematron rules before making the web service call above. I have looked at libraries like ph-schematron, but it seems like validation can only made on objects like `File` or similar. Does anyone know a way to validate an object generated with JAX-WS, like my `ProcessStuffObject`, against Schematron rules?

**Update:**
Now I have marshalled `ProcessStuffObject` to a `File` object that can be validated with ph-schematron, but this seems like a really stupid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX-WS is normally going to use JAXB to marshal objects to XML for sending over the wire and unmarshal received XML into objects. The JAXB API offers some useful stuff for transparently handling an object like XML without explicitly having to first marshal it to a file, String, byte array or other intermediate representation.

The class you need is [JAXBSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/util/JAXBSource.html). It implements [the javax.xml.transform.Source interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Source.html) and lets you provide an object and a JAXBContext or a Marshaller. You can then supply it as a source for transformations or other methods that take such an instance. Some of the ph-schematron methods accept a Source as input, [such as this one](http://phax.github.io/ph-schematron/site-4.0.0/apidocs/com/helger/schematron/ISchematronResource.html#getSchematronValidity-javax.xml.transform.Source-).

If you pre-compile the Schematron files to an XSLT you could just use the Java XML transformation API and supply the Source to the transformer.